# Current page or route that has a specific content using include method in RAILS 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I can't seem to make this work in view,

```
if current_page?(question_path).include?("Question 1")
```

I have a condition that will display a particular html element if current page detects a text which is `"Question 1"`

What is the best way to satisfy it?

Because, if I use specific route with specific ID it's not even dynamic.

```
if current_page?(question_path(1))
```

The ID: 1 can be changed if it has been deleted right?

Snippet (what I have right now):

```
.reference_display
  .reference_container
    - if current_page?(question_path).include?("Question 1")
      .reference_lip_ref
        .lip_arrow{:title => "Click to expand"} ◀
        .close_btn{:title => "Close"}
        .lip.close_btn{:title => "Close"}
        .slide
          .preloader
          %ul{"data-orbit" => "", "data-options" => "timer_container_class: hide; timer_paused_class: hide; timer_progress_class: hide; timer_speed:240000;"}
            - @question.references.order("my_order").each do |r|
              %li
                %img.referenceImage{:alt => "Reference Data", :src => "#{r.image_url}", :style => "border: 1px solid #ccc;"}/
    - elsif @questions.last
      .reference_lip
        .lip_arrow{:title => "Click to expand"} ◀
        .close_btn{:title => "Close"}
        .lip.close_btn{:title => "Close"}
        .slide
          .preloader
          %ul{"data-orbit" => "", "data-options" => "timer_container_class: hide; timer_paused_class: hide; timer_progress_class: hide; timer_speed:240000;"}
            - @question.references.order("my_order").each do |r|
              %li
                %img.referenceImage{:alt => "Reference Data", :src => "#{r.image_url}", :style => "border: 1px solid #ccc;"}/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
- if request.path.include?('suggestion')
  = your code
```

Comment: Yes. I was about to post the same.
Or even better if current_page?(question_path) && request.path.include?('suggestion')

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made it by `if (question_path).include?("Question 1")`

Comment: @xirukitepe are you sure it will work? By default, `question_path` without given question ID will raise an error.

Comment: Sorry it's not working.. and would it be possible to have it on the page itself not in the url or route/path? Because if the url doesn't have `Question 1` text, the condition will not work.

Comment: Try this: `-if current_page?(controller: :questions, action: :show) && @question.name.include?('question 1')`